# Suppose $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ let L be the set of limit points of A, show that doesn't produce new limit points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I just wanted to check if my proof is correct.
Given $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, let L be the set of all limit points of A.

Show that L is closed set.

Suppose that $\{x_n\}_{n = 1}^{\infty} \subset L$ s.t $x_n \longrightarrow x$ we wish to show that $x \in L$. Since each $x_i \in L$ is a limit point of some sequence $\{y_j^{i}\}_{j = 1}^{\infty}$ so that $y_j^i \longrightarrow x_i \longrightarrow x \implies y_u^u \longrightarrow x$ as u goes to infinity. As $\{y_m^m\}_{m = 1}^{\infty} \subset A \implies x \in L$.  I am actually stuck in the step where I want to show that $y_m^m \longrightarrow x$ as m approaches infinity. Any help in that step would be nice.

I wanted to check with everyone if my proof is correct.

Comment: Why does $y^u_u$ go to $x$? If you can explain this, then you are done.

Comment: I think I have the argument give me few minutes and I will edit my answer.

Comment: Could it not be the case that for some $p\in L$, $y_u^u=p$ for all $u$?

Comment: So if the $x_n$ sequence consists solely of the limit points of $A$ which are not in $A$ and the sequence approaches an $x$ which is not a limit point of  $A$, would it not be the case that there is an $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $x$ which contains no point of $A$ but which does contain limit points of $A$?

Comment: I don't think what I said is true..

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales But how can you be sure that neighborhood doesn't contain a point of A. For all we know it could have intersect A at a point ?

Comment: If every $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $A$ then $x$ is in $L$ but we are supposing that $x$ is a limit point of $L$ which is not in $L$.

Comment: I think my answer outlines the slickest approach.

I don't think your diagonal sequence will work, John Wayland Bale's comment gives an example as to why it doesn't work. The key thing is that it's not true that there exists an index $u$ such that $y_u^u$ is within $\epsilon$ of $x_u$. The distance between $x_u$ and $y_u^u$ can't be bound tightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to prove the below statement:

### Given $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, let L be the set of all limit points of A. Show that L is closed set.

You want to show that $L$ is a closed set. One way to do this is to show that $x$ is also a limit point of $A.$ Let $\epsilon > 0 $ be arbitrary. 
 
Let $\{x_n\}_{n = 1}^{\infty} \subset L$ be such that $x_n \longrightarrow x$. 
 Show that $(x - \epsilon, x+ \epsilon)$ intersects $A$ in a point other than $x$. Choose $i$ such that $\forall j > i$, $|x_j - x| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. $ U = (x_j -\frac{\epsilon}{2}, x_j + \frac{\epsilon}{2}) $ is a subset of $$(x - \epsilon, x+ \epsilon)$$

that intersects $A$ in $x^{*}$ due to $x_j$ being a limit point. If $x^* \ne x$, we are done. If $x^* = x$, then shrink $U$ to exclude $x$ and call this interval $U'$. $U'$ intersects $A$ in a point other than $x$ and $x_j$ and is a subset of $(x - \epsilon, x+ \epsilon)$. Thus, $x$ is a limit point of $A$. Hence $x\in L$.

Comment: Very slick proof thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I think there is a slight error. How do you know that $U = (x_j - \frac{\epsilon}{2},x_j + \frac{\epsilon}{2})$ intersect A in points other than x? I mean $x_j$ is a limit point, so U intersect A in points other than $x_j$, but it is possible that $x \neq x_j$, so it is possible to intersect in x.

Comment: You are right, I have modified the original argument.

Answer (score 0):

Tyring to follow your proof, I cannot find a way to showing that $y_u^u \to x$.
But there is an argument quite close to your approach:

For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall i \geq N$, 
$|x_i - x| < \epsilon/2$.

Furthermore, for a fixed $i$, there exists an $M_i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall j \geq M_i$, 
$|y_i^j - x_i| < \epsilon/2$.

So, there exists a sequence $y_i^{M_i} \in A$, for which we know, when $i \geq N$
$$
|y_i^{M_i} - x| \leq |y_i^{M_i} - x_i| + |x_i - x| < \epsilon.
$$

That is $x$ is a limit point of $A$.

Comment: Yeah I agree with your logic, but just at the end the inequality should be less than or equal to.

Comment: you are right. my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to  show that $y_n^n\to x$. You only need to find a sequence $z_{k}$ in $A$ such that $z_k\to x$. Here is one way you may use. We first select 
a subsequence of $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, which is still denoted by  $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$,, such that $|x_n-x|\leq \frac{1}{2^n}$. Then for each $x_n$, we can select $z_n\in A$ such that $|z_n-x_n|\leq \frac{1}{2^n}$. This is possible since each $x_n$ is the limit of some sequence $\{y^n_k\}$. You can just select one $y^n_k$ such that $|y^n_k-x_n|\leq \frac{1}{2^n}$ and denote it by $z_n$.

Then the sequence $\{z_n\}\subset A$ and 
$$
|z_n-x|\leq |z_n-x_n|+|x_n-x|\leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}.
$$
So it converges to $x$.

Comment: how do we know that $\{z_n\} \subset A$ ?

Comment: @Newbie just select $z_n\in A$

Answer (score 0):

Given that $L$ is the set of limit points of $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ show that there is no point $x$ which is a limit point of $L$ which is not also a limit point of $A$.

Suppose such an $x$ exists.

Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots \longrightarrow x$ where each $x_i\in L$.

Since by assumption $x$ is not a limit point of $A$ there is an $\epsilon$ neighborhood $N_\epsilon(x)$ of $x$ which contains no point of $A$. But since $x$ is a limit point of the sequence $\{x_i\}$, $N_\epsilon(x)$ contains a point $x_k$ of the sequence. But $x_k$ is a limit point of $A$ so $N_\epsilon(x)$  must contain a point of $A$.

This contradicts the assumption that such a point $x$ exists.

Thus every limit point of $L$ must also be a limit point of $A$.